# Angular HttpClient error handling via custom methods

Tags: angular

In my app I was planning to deal with errors in following way:

```
  return this.http.delete<IPosition>(url, {observe: 'response', headers: params.headers, params: params.queryParams})
  .flatMap<HttpResponse<IPosition>, Position>((resp) => {
    if(this.verbose){console.log(resp)}
    switch (resp.status){
      case 200: { /* Response OK */
        return Observable.of<Position>(this.positionMapper.mapInterfaceToObject(resp.body, Position) as Position)
        //return Observable.of<Position[]>(this.mapIfcToObj(resp.body) as Position[])
      }
      case 400: { /* Bad request */
        return Observable.throw(resp.body)
      }
      case 404: {
        return Observable.throw(new Error('Requested for unexisting schedule ID: '+params.path.idPosition))
      }
      case 500:{ /* Server internal erorr */
        return Observable.throw(new Error('Internal server error: ' + resp.statusText))
      }
      default: {
        throw new Error(`${resp.status}: ${resp.statusText}`)
      }
    }
  })
```

As every status except OK range ( >= 200) are intercepted by angular HttpServer, which causing all my `switch` based erorr handling procedure is never reached. I tried to use `catch` RxJS clause in between `get` and `flatMap` to simply pass through all requests:

```
  .catch((err, source) => {
    return source
  })
```

Unfortunately, this works not as I expect (though documentation says so after some research), causing whole request to re re-requested.

I' also familiar with concept of `interceptor` in new `HttpClient`, but this does not satisfy my needs: I need specific error handling for different HTTP API endpoints (i.e. sometimes 404 indeed may be an erorr, but in other case i'd like to receive empty array or empty object)

I'd appreciate any kind of help

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpClient` treats the result of all API calls resulting in a non 2xx status code, as an error. This means that the observable returned in this scenario, when calling `httpClient.post/get/etc`, would contain one item, as an error. Read [this documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html) for further info regarding Observables.

As a solution for your problem, you need to handle it this way:

```
  return this.http.delete<IPosition>(url, {observe: 'response', headers: params.headers, params: params.queryParams})
      .map((resp:HttpResponse<IPosition>) => { // Will always be a success from the API's side
           let position:IPosition = resp.body;
           // Do your 200 case here
      }).catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => { // Errors are handled with catch
          if( err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
              switch(err.status) {
                  case 400: {
                      return Observable.throw(resp.error) // This is the body of the response
                  },
                  case 404: {
                      return Observable.throw(new Error('Requested for unexisting schedule ID: '+params.path.idPosition))
                  },
                  case 500:{
                      return Observable.throw(new Error('Internal server error: ' + resp.statusText))
                  }
             }
          }

          return Observable.of(//Something generic that wasn't handled)
      });
```

Comment: According to RxJS docs value provided to `catch` operator `selector` function is feed with two values: `error` and `caught`. I thought, that simply er-emitting  `caught` (which effectively is my failed request( would let the operators chain to continue processing with `HttpResponse` observable